# comparison between 3 images

Tags: c, xcode, comparison

I wanna  compare 3 images at 3 different buttons, Xcode is allowing me to compare 2 images at a time but when i write code for 3 it gives a warning 
"comparison between pointer and integer"

```
-(void)compare
{
if (b1.currentImage==b2.currentImage==b3.currentImage)
{


    b1.enabled=NO;
    b2.enabled=NO;
    b3.enabled=NO;
    NSLog(@"%@",b1.currentImage);
    NSLog(@"%@",b2.currentImage);
}

else
{
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card.png"];
    [b1 setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  }

}
```

Comment: uh... what? is it really Xcode that warns you? I doubt, that should really be the compiler instead. Also, why would you compare image objects using `==`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your code is not doing anything remotely resembling image comparison.

Comment: this method is working for 2 images but not for 3 images thats why im trying to make it work for 3 images as well

Comment: i put 3 images in an array and call them randomly, the NSArray dont save its name when we put them in an array so thats why im applying this method to compare it through its Pointer

Comment: Maybe you want this : `(b1.currentImage==b2.currentImage) && (b1.currentImage == b3.currentImage)`.

Comment: thats works for me, thanks Micheal Walz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally spoken when you write  :

```
a == b == c
```

that actually boils down to

```
(a == b) == c
```

thus you are comparing the result of the comparision of `a` and `b` (which is of type bool regardless of the types of a and b) to `c` which is of whatever the type of `c` is.

So in your case you compare `b1.currentImage==b2.currentImage` (which is of type `int`) to `b3.currentImage` which is a pointer type.

If yo want to compare three values for equality you have to write:

`(a == b) && (a == c)` instead of `a == b == c`

Try this small program and watch what it prints out:

```
int main()
{
  int a = 2, b = 2 , c = 2 ;

  if ((a == b) && (a == c ))
  {
    printf ("(a == b) && (a == c ) is true") ;
  }

  if ((a == b == c))
  {
    printf ("(a == b == c) is true") ;
  }

  return 0 ;
}
```

it will print

```
(a == b) && (a == c ) is true
```

because `(a == b == c)` is evaluated like this

```
1.  (a == b) == c
2.  (2 == 2) == 2
3.  1 == 2
4.  false
```

Comment: thanks alot, it works for me, I had bugs in my logic